# Android Camera2 JPG to Base64 is rotated 90 degrees counter clockwise

Tags: android, base64, android-camera2

I'm working on a way to take pictures with Camera2 API. I started out by cloning Google's sample app repository.

The [sample app](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2basic/Camera2BasicFragment.java) works; it saves the image and is oriented correctly when viewed through a file browser on the device, and when I view it on my Windows machine.

However, when I attempt to replace the code that saves the image to the file system with code that converts the image to Base64, that String (when decoded) appears rotated 90 degrees counterclockwise. I've seen similar questions that claim the image itself is rotated, but in this case it's only the base64 representation. Here is the code change I made to the sample app:

```
@Override
public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
    Image image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
    ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
    byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.capacity()];
    buffer.get(bytes);

    byte[] encodedBytes = Base64.encode(bytes,Base64.NO_WRAP);
    String encodedString = new String(encodedBytes);

    Log.wtf(TAG, "Base64 JPG: " + encodedString);
}
```

I placed a breakpoint on the log line so I could pull out the entire value of the encoded String. I used several online tools such as [this one](https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter) and it appears rotated 90 degrees to the left for some reason.

Is this the wrong way to Base64 a JPG? Am I parsing the bytes incorrectly?

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with Base64 encoding. A lot of devices have 90 degrees orientation for the camera. It could change when you take the picture in landscape mode. This also changes based on OEMs. eg. Samsung has different orientation sometimes. You can get the orientation from the camera configuration.

Comment: I programmatically changed the sensor orientation by adjusting mSensorOrientation to different values, like 0, 270, etc. It results in the image saved to the file system being rotated, but the base64 String is still being decoded in the same orientation. Very confusing.

Comment: When the file is saved, it has EXIF metadata which contains the orientation and the gallery apps use that to display the correct orientation.

Comment: @Froyo Thank you. Feel free to leave this as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the encoding. Different hardware have different sensor orientations and they usually have a 90 degree orientation for the images and videos. So if you directly convert a frame to bytes, you will get the rotated image.

The camera saves the image as is but adds EXIF metadata about the orientation. The gallery app will read this orientation metadata and load the Bitmap with correct orientation.